# Using httr:GET to draw data from API into a tibble

Tags: r

I am trying to use httr:GET to draw data from the UK Parliament's API into a tibble

Using this...

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

MP <- GET("http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/id=172/GovernmentPosts%7COppositionPosts/")
MP <- as.data.frame(content(MP, as = "text", type = "xml", encoding = "UTF-8"))
MP
```

I am expecting to see data in a tibble along the lines of...

[image: This is what I get when run through PowerQuery/BI]

(This is what I get when run something similar through PowerQuery/BI)

But instead, get...

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  value                                                                                                                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                                                                                                                          
1 "{\"Members\":{\"Member\":{\"@Member_Id\":\"172\",\"@Dods_Id\":\"25790\",\"@Pims_Id\":\"3572\",\"@Clerks_Id\":\"1\",\"DisplayAs\":\"Ms Diane Abbott\",\"ListAs\":\"Abbott, Ms~
```

Have looked through similar questions here but can't work out what I'm failing to do

...

Questions below were the prod I needed, got to the stage I need through:

```
MP <- GET("http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/id=172/GovernmentPosts%7COppositionPosts/")
MP <- content(MP, as = , type = , encoding = "UTF-8")
MP
```

Comment: Can you share the raw return from your API ? I kind of doubt it is in xml format

Comment: Why aren't you just using the existing R package? https://ropengov.github.io/hansard/

Comment: re. 'Why aren't you just using the existing R package?'.  Annoyingly the members data in the http://explore.data.parliament.uk/ API are not the same as the data in the seperate Member Query Engine API - http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/memberquery.aspx - which is not accessible through the hansard package

Comment: re. 'Can you share the raw return from your API ?'  Do you mean the following "Ms Diane AbbottAbbott, Ms DianeRt Hon Diane Abbott MP1953-09-27T00:00:00FLabourCommonsHackney North and Stoke Newington1987-06-11T00:00:00Current Member2017-06-08T00:00:00Shadow Home SecretaryShadow Home Secretary2016-10-06T00:00:00FalseFalse"?  This is returned when "http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/id=172/GovernmentPosts%7COppositionPosts/" is launched through browser)

Comment: But, you could just riff off that code-base vs start from scratch and even PR into it (so the "annoyingly" — ironic b/c it's open source and you didn't pay for it — becomes a "oh, they didn't get around to that and I'll be a helpful person and fill in that gap for them").